# FilterRegistrationBean is deprecated in Spring Boot 1.4.*

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter

I upgraded Spring Boot dependency in my project and I realized that some classes, such as FilterRegistrationBean, are deprecated.

Do you know how can implement a Filter in Spring Boot 1.4.1?

Bean of Filter

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    AuthenticationFilter f = new AuthenticationFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(f);
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("defaultToken", defaultToken);
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("secretKey", secretKey);
    ArrayList<String> match = new ArrayList<>();
    match.add("/users/*");
    registrationBean.setUrlPatterns(match);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

My Filter code:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

private String defaultToken;
private String secretKey;

private UserSessionTokenRepository userSessionTokenRepository;
private UserManager userManager;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    defaultToken = filterConfig.getInitParameter("defaultToken");
    secretKey = filterConfig.getInitParameter("secretKey");
    userSessionTokenRepository = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext()).getBean(UserSessionTokenRepository.class);
    userManager = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext()).getBean(UserManager.class);
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void addHeaders(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
}

public void destroy() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It has been moved to another package: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html

Answer (score 5):

Check [the javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html). It was just moved to the package org.springframework.boot.web.servlet